# How to convert a String that contains % into an Int in Swift

Tags: swift, string, integer, percentage

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let tip = tipPercentSelected.currentTitle ?? "unknown"
    print(tip)
    }
```

'*tipPercentSelected*' here represents an amount of tips in % that can be chosen by the user, e.g. 20%. In the code this '*tipPercentSelected*' if of type String.
I need to have 0.2 instead of 20% to be printed out to console when the relevant button is pressed. However, if '*tipPercentSelected*' is converted into Int it gives *nil*

```
@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let tip = tipPercentSelected.currentTitle ?? "unknown"
    print(tip)
    let tipConverted = Int(tip)
    print(tipConverted)
    
    }
```

What code do I need to get 0.2 instead of 20%?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a string in the first place? Just keep a reference of the value when the user selects the tip percentage. Only convert the value to string to display it to the user.

Comment: @LeoDabus  the thing is that its not the beginning of the code, so at this stage faced that issue with the string conversion.  Please see below Joakim provided the answer that is ok here.

Comment: Never said it wouldn't work. My qestion is why when the user selects the percentage it  generates a string instead of the percentage value? I mean you should use number formatter to generate the string to be displayed not to parse it.

Comment: @LeoDabus  "is why when the user selects the percentage it generates a string instead of the percentage value?" - this is just a training code and is a part of the training task)

Comment: Anyway. Btw you are asking how to convert it as Int. You would need to multiply by 100 after parsing the percentage value and then coerce the floating point to an integer value.

Comment: @LeoDabus  Hey here is a method a really needed for this:  let somePercent = "20%"  then  let resultWithoutPctSign = somePercent.dropLast(1)

Comment: this assumes your last character will always be the percentage symbol. btw 1 is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `NumberFormatter` with style set to `percent`

```
let tipPercent = "20%"

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .percent

if let tip = formatter.number(from: tipPercent) {
    print(tip)
}
```

This prints 0.2

In your view controller it could be something like this

```
static private let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .percent
    return formatter
}()

func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let tip = tipPercentSelected.currentTitle, let tipConverted = Self.formatter.number(from: tip) {
        print(tipConverted)
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson  First part of your code worked just fine! Thank you

Comment: Hey hey also .dropLast method would work just fine, thus first to get rid off the percentage sign and the divide by 100

Comment: It is much better to use a NumberFormatter than manually changing the string